# Should the color of the link be changed when you click it?

Tags: hyperlinks, human-interface-guideline

Here is a question that needs to be solved. Everyone must be familiar with the #link. It can help us skip to another page. Now, [UI designers and UX designers](https://www.mockplus.com/blog/post/ui-ux-designer-description?r=cherry) hold different views. For the aesthetics of the interface,  UI designers think the link shouldn't change color when we click it. For user experience, UX designers prefers to set interaction to change the color of the link. This way can help users know which link they have clicked. What's your opinion? who do you agree with?

Comment: Are you asking for an opinion in a specific situation or is this about links in general? If it's a specific situation you should clarify and perhaps add some screenshot / mockup. Otherwise there are already usability guidelines for how to use hyperlinks.

Comment: @user96671 you have some strange ideas about UX and UI. Specifically asking for *opinion* means that you also have not read the https://ux.stackexchange.com/tour page.

Comment: Sorry, my English is not good,I think there is a place that I can ask some questions.....And, this question exist in my work, it relates to user experience,,,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should hyperlink text color be changed after visited](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/2734/should-hyperlink-text-color-be-changed-after-visited)

Answer (score 3):

**Hyperlink Usability**

Hyperlink Usability Guidelines

Irrespective of how hyperlinks are visualized, there are some basic design precepts that should be applied across the board to ensure usability:

**Hyperlink meaningful text:** Linking to a ‘click here’ label is bad for SEO and bad for users, who are implicitly forced to hunt for more information on what exactly they are clicking on. Users are wary of spyware. Let them know where the link will take them.

**Cut the blue text:** Even if your links are not blue, the colour is so strongly associated with clickability that any blue text is bound to encourage users to click. If the blue text is not clickable, this results in frustration.

**Make links obvious:** Users should not have to interact with the interface to find links

**Pick a hyperlink design and stick to it:** There should be no variation in the way links are visualized across the site
Visited links: Let users know which links they have clicked on by toning done to a ‘worn’ hue, or red-shifting the colour, as google search does from bright blue to purple-ish colour.

***Mouse-over: Links should change style on mouse-over, emphasizing to users that they are clickable***

**Padding:** Adding padding to a link makes it easier for thumb-wielding mobile users to tap in the general vicinity of a link, and still go where they want to go

Comment: +1 Seems to cover all the different context for hyperlinks